# How to display menu popup in GWT Mobile Phonegap

Tags: gwt, cordova

I'm using [gwtmobile](http://gwtmobile.com/) for implementing an iOS app, and I would like to use menu dialog like Facebook.app (when you click to show notification), so, I may insert some of menu-like content and handle it.

Are there some libraries that I can use?

Comment: After try everything, finally I develop on native.